# Write the code to process the list of words and trim any spaces out of the words

Tags: java, arrays, string

This code is supposed to check through an array of strings and see if there is a space between a word. Here is an example: {“every”, “near ing”, “ checking”, “food “, “stand”, “value “}. It should be changed to hold: {“every”, “nearing”, “checking”, “food”, “stand”, “value”}. Here is my code so far:

```
package space;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class spacefinder {
   public static void main (String[] args) {
      String[] arr = {"every", "near ing", "checking", "food", "stand", "value"};
      Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\arr");
      Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(arr);
      boolean found = matcher.find();
   }
}
```

This code results in an error, and every tutorial I see does not use a string array, such as the String[] Arr in my case, they only use a regular String = statement.

Comment: Hello, which parts of this task are not clear? Did you try anything to complete this task?  Which _specific_ issues you encountered?

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i] = arr[i].replace(" ", "");
}
```

Comment: Slava Vedenin - Note that `String#replaceAll` takes a regex as the first parameter and therefore you can use `a.replaceAll("\\s+", "")` to remove all whitespace. However, I suggest you use `a.replace(" ", "")` which is capable of replacing all occurrences of `" "` with `""`.

Comment: (1) If you are already using index then there is no reason to involve enhanced-for loop. Simple code like `for(int i = 0; i<arr.lenght; i++){ arr[i] = ... }` will be enough. (2) Instead of `replaceAll` safer option would be `replace`. Both methods will replace all specified strings, but `replaceAll` supports regex which means that if OP will want to replace something like `+` he will not be able to do it (easily). `replace` treats its arguments as literals.

Comment: `.replace(' ', '');` wouldn't compile as there is no *empty `char` literal* in Java like `''`. There is empty String like `""`. Rolled back your edit to previous version which didn't face that problem. Hope you don't mind.

Answer (score -1):

maby this wil work

```
   public static String[] removeSpace(String[] ans) {
        for(String s:ans){
            while(s.contains(" ")){
                s = s.split(" ")[0] + s.split(" ")[1];
            }
        }
        return ans;
    }
```

Comment: You don't change array element - due to string is immutable, you just change local variable without saving result to array

Comment: That will not modify element inside array. Also if string contains more than one space it will drop everything after it (since you are only reusing first and second part of split).