# Deleting whitespace within a string array

Tags: java, arrays, string, whitespace

This code is supposed to check through an array of strings and see if there is a space between a word. Here is an example: {“every”, “near ing”, “ checking”, “food “, “stand”, “value “}. It should be changed to hold: {“every”, “nearing”, “checking”, “food”, “stand”, “value”}. Here is my code so far:

```
package space;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class spacefinder {
public static void main (String[] args) {
String[] arr = {"every", "near ing", "checking", "food", "stand", "value"};
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\arr");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(arr);
boolean found = matcher.find();
}
}
```

This code results in an error, and every tutorial I see does not use a string array, such as the String[] Arr in my case, they only use a regular String = statement.

Comment: Firstly, what is the error? Also, It’s fairly clear you don’t understand what Pattern does: "\\arr" makes no sense as a regex. My advice, don’t use regex, but use `String.contains(" ")` instead

Comment: Iterate through your array with a loop. Upon each iteration, check to see if the current array string element contains at least one white-space. If so, remove any white-spaces from the string array element using the [String#replace()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_replace.htm) method: `if (arr[i].contains(" ")) { arr[i] = arr[i].replace(" ", "");  }`.

Comment: I think you have received answers to the [very same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64490612/write-the-code-to-process-the-list-of-words-and-trim-any-spaces-out-of-the-words) yesterday.

Answer (score 2):

In case you don't need to use regex and match, I tried to wrap the primitive array with List and use stream  on it to apply replaceAll() on each string on the list.

```
String[] arr = {"every", "near ing", "checking", "food", "stand", "value"};
List<String> strings = Arrays.asList(arr);
strings.replaceAll(s -> s.replaceAll("\\s","")); 
for(int i=0;i< strings.size();i++)
    System.out.println(strings.get(i));
```

output :

```
every
nearing
checking
food
stand
value
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use regex and match: (word)(whitespace)(word) then you can:

```java
String[] arr = {"every", "near ing", "checking", "food", "stand", "value"};
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\w\\s\\w");
boolean found = false;
for (String item : arr) {
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(item);
    found = matcher.find();
    if (found) {
         break;
    }
}
```

The problem in your code is that you are trying to match a pattern with an area `pattern.matcher(arr)` which is wrong. The matcher method takes a String value.
The above code iterates through the array first and matches all strings that consist of two words separated by a whitespace.
Because it was not specified in the question what should happen when when a sting matches the pattern, the above code terminates after the first match.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to fix the regex to look for spaces, e.g. `Pattern.compile("\\s+")`.

Second, you need to iterate the array and do the replacement for each string:

```java
String[] arr = {"every", "near ing", "checking", "food", "stand", "value"};

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\s+");
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i] = pattern.matcher(arr[i]).replaceAll("");
}

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

*Output*

```
[every, nearing, checking, food, stand, value]
```

Answer (score 0):

### [`String#replace`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence))

You do not need to use any regex; you can do it simply by using `String#replace` which replaces each substring of this string that matches the literal target sequence with the specified literal replacement sequence.

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] arr = { "every", "near ing", "checking", "food", "stand", "value" };
        System.out.println("Before: " + Arrays.toString(arr));
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            arr[i] = arr[i].replace(" ", "");
        }
        System.out.println("After: " + Arrays.toString(arr));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Before: [every, near ing, checking, food, stand, value]
After: [every, nearing, checking, food, stand, value]
```